# Обмен данными между Action Script 3 и Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionscript-3

Привет всем. Стоит задача - организовать обмен данными между клиентом и сервером (AS3 И RoR). Возможно, кто-то пробовал осуществить данный обмен, и может посоветовать - какой вариант наиболее подходящий на свой взгляд и объяснить почему, если это возможно.
Используется Rails 4.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- вывод данных в XML (прием от ас3 думаю почти так же) - http://richonrails.com/articles/outputting-xml-using-ruby-on-rails
- вывод в JSON - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404950/how-do-you-output-json-from-ruby-on-rails

as3 нативно поддерживает работу с XML и JSON

в плане производительности и размеров преимущество на стороне JSON

примеры отправки JSON на сервер - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486852/how-to-post-json-data-using-actionscript-3-0

Answer (score 0):

Для обмена данными в формате AMF (родной формат для Flash, полноценный вызов методов на стороне сервера, все дела) можно использовать RubyAMF - https://github.com/rubyamf/rubyamf - Там вроде даже нативный (написан на C) сериализатор есть.